# Magento 2. Can we display custom attributes on product page after SKU?

Tags: product, product-attribute, magento2.4.1

I created custom product attribute - Manufactures SKU.

Want to display in product page after SKU.
[image]

Comment: are you using a custom module or theme to display that custom attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add below code in your custom extension.

> Step 1: Please create file under path
> PackageName/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="product.info.newattribute" destination="product.info.stock.sku" after="-"/>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.newattribute" template="PackageName_Module::newattribute.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> Step 2:- Please create file newattribute.phtml under path
> PackageName/Module/view/frontend/templates/

```
<?php $product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<div class="product attribute sku">
    <strong class="type">Manufactures SKU</strong>
    <div class="value" itemprop="maufacture-sku"><?php echo $product->getSku(); ?></div>
</div>
```

Please write your attribute code instead of getSku(); in above code.

Output :- https://prnt.sc/1g43bfi

Cheers!